# What is the best way to receive a capped number of bytes from a socket?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm using a `socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM)` socket to communicate between two processes.

I'd like the receiver to receive a capped number of bytes, where the cap is quite large (in the 16MB to 64MB range).  That is, I'd like to receive a message of up to [cap] bytes, and if the message is larger than that, I'd like to stop receiving or discard the rest of the message.

From the docs, the way to do this would seem to be to use `socket.recv(bufsize=[cap])`.  But there is the following note:

> Note For best match with hardware and network realities, the value of bufsize should be a relatively small power of 2, for example, 4096.

That suggests that the buffer size is not intended for this purpose.  So, what would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Wha can you not just count up the bytes as they are received and, after receiving at least (limit-4k) bytes, call recv() with what's left over?  TBH, I don't understand you requirement fully, or what the 'message' is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a loop, as demonstrated in this [ActiveState recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/408859-socketrecv-three-ways-to-turn-it-into-recvall/).

The `bufsize` argument is best left at its default, as per the doc you quoted. Simply call `recv` and add the received byte string to your own buffer until one of these conditions is met:

- `recv` returns an empty value. This means the other end has closed the connection
- your buffer reaches its maximum allowed size (the capacity you are talking about)
- an exception is raised. This probably means the connection has been ungracefully closed - inspect the error code

Note that `recv` will block if you do not know in advance how many bytes you want to receive. Have the client send the message size beforehand to avoid this issue. But keep in mind your `recv` can still block if the connection is laggy. Use [timeouts](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html?highlight=socket.settimeout#socket.socket.settimeout) and watch for this 4th stop condition in your loop to be sure.

Comment: Thanks. I can't rely on the sender closing the connection gracefully, so having the size sent beforehand is a good suggestion. With that and/or the loop you linked to, I think I can get what I need.